# Cordova plugin camera, how use camera filters?

Tags: cordova

I'm working on a app with Phonegap and cordova.

I'm using the plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/ for take photo with my app.

My problem ? I want to use my camera filters when i take a photo with my iphone 4s or 5... When i test my app with android it's ok, i have all android filters, but when i test with an iphone 4s or 5, i haven't any filters...

I have test cordova v3.3, 3.3-rc, 3.2 and 3.4.1 and plugin camera v0.2.7, 0.2.8 and 0.2.9.

I have no idea....

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this? I've been trying things like Filterous and Caman, but they're very slow on mobile Safari/iOS it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `allowEdit: true` option ?

Comment: Hi, was a solution ever found for this?

Comment: Well, no , had to develop native filters in Objective-C